Calculating the amount of products to equal a certain amount in Python
So, I have a number which is total_ttc and products that have their original price and the tva (code attached below). What I am trying to do is find a combination of random products with random quantities who's price adds up to the total_ttc which I have already defined.
This is my existing code, this does not provide the exact total_ttc but the closest to the total_ttc
import random

total_ttc = 362400
total_amount = 0

while total_amount < total_ttc:
    random_product = random.choice(dict_products)
    random_quantity = random.randint(1, 20)

    product_name = random_product["nom d'article"]
    product_price = random_product["prix unitaire ht"]
    product_tva = random_product["taux tva"]

    calculated_price = (product_price * random_quantity) + (product_price * product_tva)

    if total_amount + calculated_price > total_ttc - 100:
        break

    total_amount += calculated_price

print(total_amount)


Does this answer your question? Find all combinations of a list of numbers with a given sum
